# How to paste macros to other sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to copy an paste object-assigned macros to another sheet using VBA.

The following code copies and pastes the formats of 1 sheet to another but not the macros within the sheet.

```
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

is there a method to paste objects as well instead of formats from one sheet to another

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your question is thin on detail, so this is rather sketchy but you get the idea.

Any macro attached to the shape will be copied.

```
Sub x()

Sheet1.Shapes(1).Copy
Sheet2.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about *shapes* assigned to a macro via their `OnAction` property, then you don't need to copy the macro.

In fact whenever you find yourself copy-pasting code anywhere, stop and think whether there's a way to avoid duplicating code - there is pretty much always a way.

Sounds like the shapes are attached to macros implemented in the sheet's code-behind.

Add a new standard module to your project, and move (cut & paste) the code there. Watch out for any [implicit ActiveSheet references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) in that code, because what `Range("A1")` does in the code-behind of a `Worksheet` module is `Me.Range("A1")`, but in a standard module is `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` (same with unqualified `Cells`, `Names`, `Columns`, `Rows`, ...): be explicit about which sheet you're working with, and all will be fine.

Now re-associate your shapes with the macro in the standard module (i.e. `Sheet1!MyMacro` becomes `MyMacro`), and now you don't need to carry any code along with the shapes you're copying.